# Rails 3 namespaced routes for admin but also for non-admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an admin area for clients which works great!

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "base#clients"
  resources :clients
end
```

I want to have the index and show actions from the app/controllers/clients_controller.rb to also work for non-admins and keep all of the admin CRUD as it is now but with the above routes I am getting an error `No route matches [GET] "/clients"` as I would have expected because I moved the routes into the admin namespace.

My question is how do I expose my non-namespace admin actions to non-admins and still maintain the admin namespace actions in my routes above?

-J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `resources :clients, :only => [:index, :show]` outside of the `:admin` namespace. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created for more options.

You can always inspect the created routes when you enter `rake routes` in your terminal.